# Limit of $x\log x\cdot f(x)$ when $f$ is integrable function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, asymptotics

Suppose that $f\in L^1(0,+\infty)$ is a monotone decreasing, positive function. Prove that $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}x(\log x)\cdot f(x)=0.$$

Comment: xln(x)f(x)  $\qquad$ or  $\qquad$  xln(xf(x))??

Comment: $f(x) x \ln x $

Comment: The problem is to see whether there is a sequence $\{t_k\}$ of real numbers, increasing to $+\infty$ and such that the series $\sum_k\frac{t_k-t_{k-1}}{t_k\log t_k}$ is convergent.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Good analysis. There is.

Comment: Yes, for example $t_k=2^{k^2}$.

Comment: OP: To modify drastically the question after some answers are posted is contrary to the policy of the site (and to politeness, I should add). Please do not do this. If you have a question different from the one posted, then post another question. (I reverted your question to its previous version.)

Comment: I am very sorry. I tried to post another question but the system told me that it is the same as the above one. I would like to post now the question with the additional condition, f to be convex. Could anybody help me to post the new question?

Comment: @kmitov did you find an answer when $f$ is supposed to be convex ?

Answer (score 4):

The assertion is not true. Consider 
$$
f_0=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}(n^2\mathrm e^{n^2})^{-1}\mathbf 1_{[0,\mathrm e^{n^2}]},
$$
then $f_0$ is nonincreasing, $g_0(x)=f_0(x)x\log(x)$ does not converge to zero when $x\to\infty$ since $g_0(\mathrm e^{n^2})\geqslant1$ for every $n\geqslant1$, and the integral of $f_0$ is $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}n^{-2}$, which is finite, hence $f_0$ is integrable.

One can modify this example slightly to get a decreasing function $f$, for example 
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}(n^2\mathrm e^{n^2})^{-1}\exp(-x\mathrm e^{-n^2})\mathbf 1_{[0,\mathrm e^{n^2}]}(x).
$$
Then $f$ is decreasing, $g(x)=f(x)x\log(x)$ does not converge to zero when $x\to\infty$ since $g(\mathrm e^{n^2})\geqslant\mathrm e^{-1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$, and $f\leqslant f_0$ hence $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Do you mean $f_0(x)=\sum_{n \ge 1}(n^2e^{n^2})^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,e^{n^2}]}(x)?$ If so, why the integral of $f_0(x)$ is $\sum_{n \ge 1}n^{-2}$?

Comment: Because the integral of $c\mathbf 1_{[0,a]}$ with $a\gt 0$ is $ac$.

Comment: What motivated the definition of $f_0$?

Comment: The conditions have been changed. Is the answer correct now?

Comment: See my comment to the main post.

Comment: I am very sorry. I tried to post another question but the system told me that it is the same as the above one. I would like to post now the question with the additional condition, $f$ to be convex. Could anybody help me to post the new question?

Comment: @Did Why $g_0(e^{n^2})=1$? I think that  $g_0(e^{n^2})>1.$

Comment: Indeed, $g_0(\mathrm e^{n^2})\geqslant1$, not $g_0(\mathrm e^{n^2})=1$, thanks. (Would you be preparing yourself to *accept* an answer, 5+ years after the facts, by any chance? :-))

Comment: The problem arised again these days and I remembered that I had  the answer, but now I look at it more carefully. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent! $ $ $ $

Answer (score -3):

I think it's not true, for example $f(x)=1/x$

and we have

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}xln(x)(1/x)=+\infty$

Comment: But $\int_0^\infty \frac 1 x$ does not exist IIRC

Comment: why do you check integral?

Comment: $f \in L^1(0,\infty)$ means that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$

Answer (score -3):

Edit: This argument assumes that the limit exists, which need not happen.

A change of variables gives, for $a>1$,
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{xln(x)} = \int_{\ln(a)}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u} =\infty
$$
If the limit was not zero, call it $L$ (admitting $L=\infty$), we would get, for $x>a$ (with $a$ large enough) $f(x)\geq \frac{L}{2} \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$ if $L$ is finite and $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$ if it's infinite. Either way it contradicts the integrability of $f$ by the initial remark.

Comment: How do you know that the limit exists? The assumption would be that the $\limsup$ is not $0$.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. For some reason I took $f$ to be increasing. I'll leave the answer though because the argument works if the limit is assumed to exist.